# React Native : replace a string with a Text component

Tags: react-native

I am trying to convert some homemade tags/bbcode and for doing so I need in some case not to return a string but a text component, I am trying to do that with this small function but the issue is that when I render it it display [object Object] instead of the component.

*helper.js*

```
import { Text } from "react-native";
    const decodeTags = (string) => {
      string = string.replace(
        /\[b\](.+)\[\/b\]/isu,
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>$1</Text>
);
```

*profilBio.js*

```
<Text style={styles.bio}>
  {decodeTags(props.profil.bio)}
</Text>
```

Render

> [object Object] (instead of some text with a part in bold)

Comment: I wouldn't suggest to call a function within the Text component.  Format your string beforehand, store it in a state or similar and pass that to the Text component.

Comment: How you can format that ? I will end with nested Text anyway no ?

Comment: Ah sorry - I see in some cases you are returning a Text component, not always a string.  Why? If because of the styling, you can change that conditionally.  If because of the content, that can be updated conditionally too. I'll post an example..

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some pre-processor function which would basically split the string  at the string which you need to make bold. After that, just basic string `substring` operation and concatenating the parts.

Ex:

```js
const highlightKeyword = useCallback((originalString = '', searchQuery) => {
  let s = originalString;
  let searchStartIndex = s.indexOf(searchQuery);
  return (
    <Text>
      <Text style={Styles.text}>{s.substr(0, searchStartIndex)}</Text>
      <Text style={[Styles.text, {color: Colors.RED}]}>{searchQuery}</Text>
      <Text style={Styles.text}>
        {s.substr(searchStartIndex + searchQuery.length, s.length)}
      </Text>
    </Text>
   );
}, []);

highlightKeyword(props.profil.bio,searchQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the request is how to update styles conditionally;

To update styles conditionally;

```
  <Text style={(this.state.myCondition == true) ? styles.bio_font_weight : styles.bio}>{decodeTags(props.profil.bio)}</Text>
```

And update `decodeTags()` to return only the data, not a Text component.

Comment: That would change the whole text, not some words, I need only the words between the tags to be changed.